# ruby array of structs

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, struct, aws-sdk

I need to extract a tag value from `AWS EC2` using the `AWS ruby-sdk v2` to get information about instances.  The tags are manually set for the most part.

When I get tags back from the following code:

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(:region => us-east-1)
ec2.instances.limit(10).each do |instance|  
  instance.tags.each do |tag|       
    puts tag   
  end
end
```

I see:

```
#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="Owner", value="the_owner">
#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="PurchaseOrder", value="90210">
#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="Name", value="my_rocking_instance">
#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="environment", value="staging">

#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="Name", value="another_instance">
#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="environment", value="prod">
#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="PurchaseOrder", value="90210">
#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="Owner", value="the_owner">
```

and so on.  I put a space between the two instances for clarity.  I tried a few tricks with arrays, hashes, etc. but this appears to be an array of structs which I haven't worked with yet.

How do I extract only the `Name` tag value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so

```
ec2.instances.limit(10).each do |instance|  
  instance.tags.each do |tag|       
    puts tag.value if tag.key == 'Name'
  end
end
```

Or you could also use something like this to return an array of instance tag values (which have the key **Name**).

```
ec2.instances.limit(10).flat_map(&:tags).map{|x| x.value if x.key == 'Name'}.compact
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you @nabeel-amjad!  +1 and bonus points for the array of instance tag values.